# mongodb fast upsert creates new documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a scenario where i need to maintain a date and a count for that. In some cases the count need to be incremented very fast.

I'm using the following code to increment the count:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
MyModel.update({date:today},{$inc:{count:1}},{upsert:true}).exec(function(err,result)
{
    if(err)
        console.error(err);
});
```

But sometimes when the function is called extremely fast, upsert creates multiple new documents.

The first time I has 200 upserts, and it did the following:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577fb98670e5b643e77584ce"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-07-07T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "count" : 197
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577fb98670e5b643e77584cf"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-07-07T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "count" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577fb98670e5b643e77584d0"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-07-07T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "count" : 1
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577fb98670e5b643e77584d1"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-07-07T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "count" : 1
}
```

Is there any way to solve this except creating the document in advance?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

as was thinking about that - you could set `_id` field using `data` value, so first will be created and next ones will get `duplicated key exception` and you could retry that action.

**END EDIT**

As this call comes from async environment, first 4 calls were executed and cannot find a value - so new documents were created, and then all updates were redirected to first created document.

If we try to create document first - we could still have same issue here, so the document need to be created let's say a few minutes ahead to avoid race.

Any comments welcome!

**EDIT**
Did you created an index on that field ?

This screenshot below is when you use _id field as unique time vale time

[image]

this one is whe you create unique index (and ensure it is created)

[image]

Comment: ahh i thought of making the date unique, but just that wouldnt help so dropped the plan. Didnt think of handling when the exception is thrown! This might work as I said I dont want to create the doc ahead of time, that would be too much of code.

Comment: not working :(
I set `unique:true` for the date field. Still multiple docs get created

Comment: I'm not doing it in shell. I did it in my mongoose schema. Actually its not giving me the duplicate error, but its not creating multiple docs either. I'm testing it.

Comment: ok, you can use mongose to cretae unque index see this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/indexes.html

Comment: Yes, that what I'm saying, I've done it. But its not throwing the error. So I'm not sure if its working or not. Still need to test it more.

Comment: The multiple docs were getting created because I was dropping the collection while testing the code, and mongoose was not recreating the index again. I guess once the index is created, it does not even try to create the new document, so the error is not thrown.

Comment: that could be a case, even when collection was dropped all writes are held in queu

Comment: and as mongoose is not recreating the index, multiple docs are getting created

Comment: are you able to do it via mongo shell?

Comment: i havent tried. Anyways, the solution works, maybe it finds the doc because its indexed. I'll test more and select it as answer if i dont find any problem. Thanks! :)